なんて　なんと　なんか　are they all changeable?
Can all of them be interchangeable? When do I use them? What were the original forms of these words? Can all of them be used before, between, after nouns, verbs, adjectives? Which is prioritised over which? I’m so clueless.

This kind of question is easier to answer when you provide examples that you find confusing to distinguish between the various options.

I have no examples cause I literally have no idea what I should give. I just what the basic usage of it that can cover most.

You could probably spend several pages trying to answer this question. As Leebo says, example sentences to answer specific examples would be better. You must have seen example sentences in the past to know that these words exist. Perhaps it would be best to make a new question next time you come across an example that bothers you, To answer your title question though, no, they are not generally interchangeable.

Yes in some usages, no in others.
There are basically three loci to consider:
post-positional particles
In this case, they are all interchangeable. Examples of this usage are after nouns: “恋人なんかいらない”, where it can be replaced with “〜など" “〜なんて”, “〜なんざ” and what not with little change in meaning except for formality. This usage can also after verbs as in “愛してなどいない” or adjectives “寂しくなんてない”. This sense denotes dismissiveness, incredulousness to mild offense at a suggestion and the literal meaning of providing examples in a list. It should be noted that while the “XやYなんて” pattern does seem to occur, it is far, far more common with “〜など” to literally denote an inexaustive list.
post-sentence particles
This sense is not the same as after verbs. This is “愛しているなんて”. Here, only “〜なんて”　and “〜など” can be used. This sense denotes wonder or disbelief, not necessarily with the same negativity as the above sense, and also nominalizes the clause allowing it to be used as the subject or object of a sentence in for instance “勝ったなんて信じられない” to mean “I can't believe we actually won.”; here the sense of wonder is positive. We cannot use “〜なんか” or “〜なんざ” as this nominalizer.
adverbs
Here, only “なんか” and “なんて” can be used and they have very different meanings, both contractions from different things. “なんか” as an adverb is a contraction of “なにか” and denotes that one isn't quite sure of how to describe something, or the origin or reason of something, as in “なんか気持ち悪いよ” for “It's kind of disgusting you know.” “なんて" as an adverb however is short for “なんという” and again denotes wonder. As in “なんて美しい顔！” for “What beautiful a face he has!” and sounds somewhat grandiose much as the English phrase, even more so when using “なんという”.
I suppose Is should also note the technical fourth usage “なんか” as a noun, again short for “なにか”; it simply means “something” as in “なんかあったの？” to mean “Something happened?”

I think that なんと (not just なんという) can be also used as adverb, and I am not sure if it is ever used as what you called post-positional particle (you wrote "In this case, they are all interchangeable.").
